# How to update Tomcat wtpwebapps\ROOT folder?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

I have a question about how to update the `ROOT` folder every time I start or restart Tomcat from Eclipse.

I work with:

- Eclipse Juno Service Release 2
- Server: Tomcat 7

How I start Tomcat 7:

1. Servers view, open Add and Remove dialogue, and add project: **MyNewProject**.
2. Result: In `wtpwebapps` as expected is a folder `MyNewProject` created with its resources.
3. Copy folder MyResources into `wtpwebapps\ROOT`.
4. Start Tomcat and open the home page.
5. Result: the page is open and the resources are available.

What I am trying to do is have step 3 perform automatically, because these resources have to be in the `ROOT` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way of exposing your 'MyResources' under 'Root' context.

1. Double click on your server to open server properties
2. Click on the 'Modules' tab.
3. Select 'Add External Web Module'.
4. In 'Doucument Base' navigate to your 'MyResources' directory.
5. In Path specify '/'

Now, let's say you had the file 'MyResources/index.html', you can access it at following URL -

"localhost:8080/index.html"

Comment: Hi thank you for your ansewr. I am sorry that I am answering only now. I tried but it didn't create the folder MyResources nor MyResources/Index.html. I selected the External Web Module and in Document Base the MyResources directory. But it didn't work.